# Can I use setStyle() to directly change a Node's substructure class style?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I have an object that implements a custom ProgressBar. Sometimes I want the bar's track to have a white color and sometimes I want it to be black. I found that can set the default value for it in my .css file by using the following:

```
.my-bar .track {
    -fx-background-color: bar-default-color;
}
```

I hoped I could vary that color in the constructor based on passed in value settings. But despite Googling all over for it I have yet to find an example where Node.setStyle() is used to change a Substructure class' style. Calling setStyle("-fx-background-color: desired-color") directly on the ProgressBar object creates odd colors that do not match what I wanted. I'm sure that's because I need to set it on the .track Substructure instead of the parent class. So how do I access and change it via code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot be directly changed the CSS property through the setStyle() but (as an alternative for lookup) it is possible to change the color used in CSS property, These colors are defined in modena.css `.root`.

So for your use case, the progress bar track is defined as:

```
.progress-bar > .track {
      -fx-background-color: 
          -fx-shadow-highlight-color,
          linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
          linear-gradient(to bottom, 
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -7%),
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, 0%),
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -3%),
            derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%)
          );
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0, 1 1 2 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 4, 3, 2; /* 10, 9, 8 */
}
```

Here the `-fx-shadow-highlight-color`, `-fx-text-box-border` and `-fx-control-inner-background` are predefined colors. They can be changed by setStyle:

```
progBar.setStyle( "-fx-control-inner-background: aqua; 
                   -fx-text-box-border: red; 
                   -fx-shadow-highlight-color:yellow"
                );
```

Comment: At first this didn't work but it started to after I removed the -fx-background-color line from my css file. That said, it isn't a perfect solution. I want the track bar to be a single solid color (I used the same color for each of the 3 css properties). But using your method, especially with white and other lighter colors, there is a minor but noticeable gradient effect. No doubt this comes from those linear-gradient derive lines in modena.css. When I set -fx-background-color in my css it overrides it. But by your method we are working with the modena rules which include a gradient.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the node with styleclass `.track` from the `ProgressBar` by using [lookup( )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-) on it and then apply style to it :

```
final Node track = progressBar.lookup(".track");
track.setStyle("-fx-background-color: desired-color");
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that I'm trying to set the color when the object is instantiated before the application is displaying (before show()). It doesn't appear that the substructures get created until after show is called, so I always end up with null from the lookup. Another solution I found online that said to use getChildrenUnmodifiable() to get the list of sub classes and look through them ran into the same problem. The Node list it returned was always empty until after show().