# How do I change the Slider tick label color

Tags: javafx

That's my slider:

```
Slider slider = new Slider();
slider.setMin(0);
slider.setMax(100);
slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
slider.setMajorTickUnit(10);
```

And I would like to change the color of the tick label. I tried this:

```
slider.setStyle("-fx-tick-label-fill: #ffffff;");
```

But it doesn't work. How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX Slider: Track length? Tick Label Color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061828/javafx-slider-track-length-tick-label-color)

Comment: I want to change the slider directly using setStyle(), I would like to know if it is possible. I Don't want to create a separate css file

Comment: You can't do it directly, but this question does have a work around https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058128/can-i-use-setstyle-to-directly-change-a-nodes-substructure-class-style

Comment: Alright, thank you anyway.